# Re-ask: Need help to prove that the following sequence is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $a_n>0$, and the following attitude is true. Prove that the sequence is convergent.
>
> $$a_n<a_{n-1}+\frac1{2^n},\quad n\ge2$$

So, what I tried here is to simply write down the elements of the sequence. If we have a "big enough" $n$, then $\frac12^n$ will converge to $0$, so what we have left is $a(n) < a(n-1)$
(the $n$-th element is smaller than the $n-1$-th element), which means that this sequence monotonically decreasing, after a big enough $n$.

Since this is a monotonically decreasing sequence, if we can find a number as a limit, then it must be convergent, but I can't find any.

Am I thinking wrong or what should be the correct way?

Comment: You also need the assumption that $a_n$ is increasing. Otherwise, $a_n = -n$ satisfies your assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,
because your "reason" is the same
if the
$\frac1{2^n}$
is replaced by
$\frac1{n}$,
but in this case the
$a_n$ can diverge.

You have to look at the particular
bound.
In this case,
$a_n-a_{n-1}
< \frac1{2^n}
$.

If we sum this for a series
of $n$,
the left side telescopes like this:
$(a_1-a_0)+(a_2-a_1)+(a_3-a_2)+(a_4-a_3)+
...+(a_n-a_{n-1})
= a_n-a_1
$.
The right side is
$\frac12 + \frac14 + \frac1{8} + \frac1{16}+
... + \frac1{2^n}
=1-\frac1{2^n}
$.

Therefore
$a_n-a_1
< 1-\frac1{2^n}
< 1
$,
so
$a_n < 1+a_1$.

Comment: But that last part just shows the sequence is bounded -- to conclude, you need to elaborate a bit more (e.g., by showing that it can only have one adherence value, which then gives the result as it must have one by boundedness)

Comment: A bounded increasing sequence is convergent. You do not say that $a_n$ is increasing. If $a_n = -n$, then $a_n-a_{n-1} = -1 < 1/2^n$.

Comment: Well, $a_n$ is positive, though.

Comment: True. I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

An idea: I think you can prove that $(a_n)$ is cauchy by using the telescoping trick and the triangle inequality: For instance, let $m > n > 0$ and write

$$ | a_n - a_m | = |(a_n - a_{n-1}) + a_{n-1} - .... + (a_{m+1} - a_m) |$$

and use triangle inequality and we know you can make $\frac{1}{2^n} $ small as you want.

Comment: You might have a jump down that is larger than $1/2^k$

Comment: What shall I write with the trinagle inequality, I'm not quite sure. :)